# How to cast pointer to base type conditionally given a pointer to derived type

Tags: c++, pointers, casting

I have two derived classes, `Triangle` and `Sphere`, from base class `Shape`.

I have a situation where I stored a base class pointer, `Shape*` in class `A`, and have two overloaded member functions of class `A` for each derived type, `doSomething(Sphere* sp)` and `doSomething(Triangle* tr)`.

```
class Shape
{
public:
    Shape() {};
    virtual ~Shape() = 0;
};

class Triangle : public Shape
{
public:
    Triangle();
};

class Sphere : public Shape
{
public:
    Sphere();
};

class A
{
private:
    Shape* shape;
    void doSomething(Triangle* tr);
    void doSomething(Sphere* sp);
public:
    A();
    ~A();
};
```

However, when I try to run my code by passing pointer of type `Shape*` into `doSomething` function, I get following error:

```
candidate function not viable: cannot convert from base class pointer 'value_type'
      (aka 'Shape *') to derived class pointer 'const Triangle *' for 1st argument
void A::doSomething(Triangle* tr) {
```

And same message for `Sphere`. I'm also sure that although the pointer of type `Shape *`, that it actually points to one of the derived objects.

**So, how could I resolve this issue preferably without modifying `Triangle` and `Sphere` classes and only modifying `A`?**

Comment: Regardless of the ability of people to read-between-the-lines and deduce what you are asking about, it is always much more helpful if you include code.  Consider editing to supply a ["Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Overload-resolution is purely a compile-time thing. If the dynamic type is different from the static type, you can test that with `dynamic_cast` `typeid` or different behavior of `virtual`-functions at runtime. Precondition is that the static type (which is the base-class-type) has at least one `virtual` function or base.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to do this in C++. The only way to do dynamic dispatch is to call a virtual method:

```
shape->doSomething();
```

Where maybe `Triangle::doSomething` and `Sphere::doSomething` are different implementations of the virtual `Shape::doSomething`.

So either you will need to change your code structure so that it's the `shape` itself that controls the calling. Or... you can have a massive branch where you try each one in turn:

```
void doSomething() {
    if (Triangle* t = dynamic_cast<Triangle*>(shape)) {
        doSomething(t);
    }
    else if (Sphere* s = dynamic_cast<Sphere*>(shape)) {
        doSomething(s);
    }
    // etc.
}
```

I would recommend not doing that though. In additional to being awful to read, it's also slow and unmaintainable.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `dynamic_cast` to find out which derived class the `Shape*` is pointing at and get a pointer to that class, then you can pass that pointer to your `doSomething()` overloads as needed, eg:

```
class A
{
private:
    Shape* shape;
    void doSomething(Shape* sh);
    void doSomething(Triangle* tr);
    void doSomething(Sphere* sp);
public:
    A();
    ~A();
};

void A::doSomething(Shape* sh)
{
    if (Sphere *sp = dynamic_cast<Sphere*>(sh))
        doSomething(sp);

    else if (Triangle *tr = dynamic_cast<Triangle*>(sh))
        doSomething(tr);
}
```

Comment: Note that this is usually considered bad practice, and virtual functions are much preferred.

Comment: I agree, but that possibility is not allowed by the question's requirements.

Answer (score -1):

There must be some decision process in order to choose between a Sphere or a Triangle.

if you decide what shape you want at compile time, it is possible keep your design, with partial template specialization. (this sample has been compiled with g++ 4.7.2)

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

struct Shape
{
};

struct Sphere : Shape
{
    double radius;
    Sphere(double radius): radius(radius) {}
};

struct Triangle : Shape
{
    double a, b, c;
    Triangle(double a, double b, double c): a(a), b(b), c(c) {}
};

void foo(Sphere * b)
{
    cout << "Sphere " << b->radius << endl;
};

void foo(Triangle * c)
{
    cout << "Triangle " << c->a << ',' << c->b << ',' << c->c << endl;
};

template<bool>
struct ShapeShifter
{
};

template<>
struct ShapeShifter<true>
{
    typedef Sphere* Type;
};

template<>
struct ShapeShifter<false>
{
    typedef Triangle* Type;
};

int main()
{
    Shape * a1 = new Sphere(1.5);
    Shape * a2 = new Triangle(3,4,5);
    const int x = 0;

    foo(static_cast<ShapeShifter<x == 0>::Type>(a1));
    foo(static_cast<ShapeShifter<x != 0>::Type>(a2));
}
```

otherwise you can, as pointed out, use `dynamic_cast`.

Comment: This approach is error prone. I changed a1 and a2 in the function calls and the program still compiled, and printed values.

Comment: So you're just arbitrarily casting `Shape` down to `Triangle` or `Sphere` without any runtime information? Yeah, I'd call that error prone!